# how to give border-left none to the first visible child of the list?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wants to create something like this

[image]

but I have mange the following

[image]

how can I give border-left :none to the first visible child?

I am not able to create the same example but you can get an Idea from my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qrw3daqc/26/).

```
<body onload='getAllListItems()'>
    <div id='t'>

    <button id='left' onClick="move(left)">
        <</button>
            <div id='list'>
                <ul id='list-items'>
                <li class="list">slide1</li>
                <li class="list">slide2</li>
                <li class="list">slide3</li>
                <li class="list">slide4</li>
                <li class="list">slide5</li>
                <li class="list">slide6</li>
                <li class="list">slide7</li>
                <li class="list">slide8</li>
                <li class="list">slide9</li>
                <li class="list">slide10</li>
                <li class="list">slide11</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        <button id='right' onClick='move(right)'>></button>
 </div>        
</body>

ul {
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    width: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#t{
    background-color:#f16f00;
    border: 1px #ffffff solid;
}
ul li {
    border-left: 1px solid;
            border-left-color: #f16f00;
            color: #ffffff;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100px;
            height: 50px;
            float: left;
            list-style-type: none;
            background-color:#032258;
            padding-top: 0;
            padding-bottom: 0;
}
ul li:first-child {
    display: block;
}
#left, #right {
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    background-color:aqua;
    font-size:2em;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right:20px;
}



 var list_items = [];
    var index = 0;
    var list_length = 0;

    function getAllListItems() {
        var temp = document.getElementsByClassName('list');
        console.log(temp);
        for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            list_items.push(temp[i]);
        }

        list_length = temp.length;
    }

    getAllListItems();

    function move(dir) {

        if (dir === left) {
            var k = index + 1;
            console.log('i:'+index);
            console.log('k:'+k);
            list_items[index].style.display = 'block';
            list_items[index].style.border = 'none';
            index--;

            list_items[k].style.borderleft = '1px solid #425982';

            if (index < 0) {
                index = 0;
            }
        } else if (dir === right) {

            list_items[index].style.display = 'none';





   if (index >= ((list_length) - 1)) {
            index = (list_length) - 1;
        } else {
            index++;
        }
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qrw3daqc/28/  You already have a class called ul li:first-child

Comment: Is there a stress on first **visible** child (as in, do you have cases where the first child of the `ul` is not visible)?

Comment: yeah bcoz if i press right arrow the first child will not be visible

Comment: @SandhyaGor: Ok, please add that comment to the question and highlight it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ul li:first-child {
    display: block;
    border-left:0px solid red;
}
```

> You already have a class called `ul li:first-child` just add  `border-left:0px solid red;` to it.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qrw3daqc/27/)

> Sorry see the below code for the answer you needed. Your question
>   wasn't good enough to understand at one shoot

```js
 var list_items = [];
    var index = 0;
    var list_length = 0;

    function getAllListItems() {
        var temp = document.getElementsByClassName('list');
        console.log(temp);
        for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            list_items.push(temp[i]);
        }

        list_length = temp.length;
    }

    getAllListItems();

    function move(dir) {

        if (dir === left) {
            var k = index + 1;
            console.log('i:'+index);
            console.log('k:'+k);
            list_items[index].style.display = 'block';
            list_items[index].style.borderLeft = 'none';
            index--;
            
            list_items[k].style.borderLeft = '1px solid #f16f00';

            if (index < 0) {
                index = 0;
            }
        } else if (dir === right) {

            list_items[index].style.display = 'none';
 list_items[index+1].style.borderLeft = '0px solid red';


            if (index >= ((list_length) - 1)) {
                index = (list_length) - 1;
            } else {
                index++;
            }
        } else {
        }
    }
```

```css
ul {
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    width: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#t{
    background-color:#f16f00;
    border: 1px #ffffff solid;
}
ul li {
    border-left: 1px solid;
            border-left-color: #f16f00;
            color: #ffffff;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100px;
            height: 50px;
            float: left;
            list-style-type: none;
            background-color:#032258;
            padding-top: 0;
            padding-bottom: 0;
}
ul li:first-child {
    display: block;
    border-left:0px solid red;
}
#left, #right {
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    background-color:aqua;
    font-size:2em;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right:20px;
}
```

```html
<body onload='getAllListItems()'>
    <div id='t'>
    
    <button id='left' onClick="move(left)">
        <</button>
            <div id='list'>
                <ul id='list-items'>
                <li class="list">slide1</li>
                <li class="list">slide2</li>
                <li class="list">slide3</li>
                <li class="list">slide4</li>
                <li class="list">slide5</li>
                <li class="list">slide6</li>
                <li class="list">slide7</li>
                <li class="list">slide8</li>
                <li class="list">slide9</li>
                <li class="list">slide10</li>
                <li class="list">slide11</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        <button id='right' onClick='move(right)'>></button>
 </div>        
</body>
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qrw3daqc/30/)

> Chnages in you css

```
ul li:first-child {
    display: block;
    border-left:0px solid red;
}
```

> Change in your JS

```
    function move(dir) {

    if (dir === left) {
        var k = index + 1;
        console.log('i:'+index);
        console.log('k:'+k);
        list_items[index].style.display = 'block';
        list_items[index].style.borderLeft = 'none';
        index--;

        list_items[k].style.borderLeft = '1px solid #f16f00';

        if (index < 0) {
            index = 0;
        }
    } else if (dir === right) {

        list_items[index].style.display = 'none';
         list_items[index+1].style.borderLeft = '0px solid red';


        if (index >= ((list_length) - 1)) {
            index = (list_length) - 1;
        } else {
            index++;
        }
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: I have seen the damo sry but there is no diff?

Comment: can you please highlight the changes my code has been mashed up so I ma not able to rectify it

Comment: I hvae same Code still its not working .. right arrow is working fine but there is a problem with left arrow.I am posting an image of js code to my answer you can check it

Comment: @SandhyaGor `list_items[k].style.borderLeft = '1px solid #f16f00';` the borderLeft in your case the `L` is in small letter check it out.

Comment: Thank you so much Nice observation you made my problem Solve.

Comment: just border-left: 0; and that's it.

Comment: @Kawinesh Sk I need your guidelines to this question. [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025665/how-to-show-big-data-in-different-cols-of-the-bootstrap-and-give-pagination-to-t)